# How to express the willingness to learn things necessary on the job?

Tags: grammar, sentence

I am applying for a job in finance where I think I am just a beginner. So there are a lot of things I will learn on the job. I want to express that I am ready for it and to make clear that I am an career entrant. I thought about something like:

```
"I am willing to enhance my knowledge in finance."
```

I am not happy with this and I do not know how to express what I want in a nice sentence. So I want to state that I am ready to expand my knowledge where it is necessary and that I am eager to learn new technologies (which are necessray for this) job on the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

> "I am keen to learn more about finance and the technologies required to work with it".

'Finance' is a very general term that encompasses a multitude of specialized evils. In your situation, I think I'd try to replace it with a term that narrows the focus of interest, and  which therefore makes it seem as though you have a firmer sense of the direction you want to pursue within this large field.

Comment: Thanks! I am applying as a quantitative analyst and in the job offer in one point it says something about the skills in "finance and technology". So I wanted to respond to this in a  general way. "Specialized evils" is interesting word choice :-) !

Comment: Yes. It's deliberate.  :-)

Comment: But why do you think evil?

Comment: Because it seems to me that in recent years, the average person has suffered considerable ill effects from the activities of persons and institutions operating in the financial sector.

Answer (score 0):

You may say:

*I have always been interested in financial and economic issues and with a job in this field I want to improve my knowledge and my skills in this sector.*

As mentioned, the financial business is very large, so you had better add you personal attitudes to make clear which financial sectors you may fit better. ( analyst, researcher, asset  management ect.)