# 'things necessary' and 'necessary things' - same meaning?

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

Take these two sentences -

1) How to express the willingness to learn **things necessary** on the job?

2) How to express the willingness to learn **necessary things** on the job?

Are they grammatically correct? and do they convey the same meaning?

How about:

3) I usually list **necessary things** before I go to the supermarket.

4) I usually list **things necessary** before I go to the supermarket.

Grammatically correct? same meaning?

Another one:

5) [10 **Necessary Things** to Learn Before Traveling to a Foreign Country](https://www.govisitcostarica.com/blog/post/10-necessary-things-learn-before-traveling-foreign-country.aspx)

6) 10 **things necessary** to Learn Before Traveling to a Foreign Country

Comment: This might be an interesting question.  But first you need to give the promised context.  That means:  1) complete sentences; 2) some idea of what you have been able to find out by carrying out some sort of research yourself.

Comment: I've replaced the 'meaning-in-context' tag with 'sentence-meaning', which is what I'm after. (1) and (2) is based on something appearing on this very forum: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167653/how-to-express-the-willingness-to-learn-things-necessary-on-the-job. (3) and (4) is something I would say to a friend. for (5) and (6) - see link attached to (5)

Answer (score 1):

*The below is based on experience as a native speaker. I have no idea how to research it. I probably use wrong terminology. I'm more than happy to remove my answer if someone provides a better referenced answer.*

---

In any of your phrases with "**necessary things**" *necessary* is an adjective modifying *things*. All of your examples of this are valid usages.

---

In a phrase with "**things necessary** for xyz" there is an ellipsis; what it means is "**things *that are* necessary** for xyz". When speaking there would be a pause between "things" and "necessary".

Further, *necessary for xyz* is essentially an adjective describing *things*. Note that *necessary* on its own is **not** the adjective here, the whole *necessary for xyz* is the adjective.

---

Let's then have a look at what your sentences mean:

> 1) How to express the willingness to learn things necessary on the job?

This sentence is about things that are "*necessary on the job*", and is asking about learning them. It makes grammatical sense, but it may not be what you intended.

> 2) How to express the willingness to learn necessary things on the job?

This sentence is about things that are "*necessary*", and is asking about learning them on the job.

> 3) I usually list necessary things before I go to the supermarket.

This sentence is about things that are *necessary*, and listing them before going to the supermarket. It makes grammatical sense, but it would sound more idiomatic if you replaced "necessary things" with "the necessities".

> 4) I usually list things necessary before I go to the supermarket.

This sentence is about things that are "*necessary before going to the supermarket*", and listing them. Although still grammatical, this makes little logical sense. What is necessary before going to the supermarket? Probably writing a shopping list. So this sentence says "I write a list, and on that list is only one item, which is *make a shopping list*". It doesn't make much sense.

> 5) 10 Necessary Things to Learn Before Traveling to a Foreign Country

This sentence is about things that are *necessary*, and that you should learn before travelling to a foreign country. This sentence makes sense.

> 6) 10 things necessary to Learn Before Traveling to a Foreign Country

This sentence is about things that are "*necessary to learn before travelling to a foreign country*". This sentence makes sense.

Comment: Re. (3). Agreed. 'the necessities' sounds much nicer. BTW, do we need 'the'. Can I not just say 'I usually list necessities before....'. Also, isn't the second 'I' superfluous.

Could we simply say 'I usually list necessities before going to the supermarket'

(4) - You are correct. it's as if I'm referring to making a list of things needed to go on the shopping trip. e.g. pair of boots, a map, a sweater. Although, I very much doubt anyone makes such a list.

Perhaps this might work: 

I usually list necessary things before I go camping.

Comment: @wordplay - I agree with everything in your comment.